# Prove that the image of $D$ is the superior half plane

Tags: complex-analysis

I have an exercise left without correction, and I'm struggling; if anyone could help, it would be a lot appreciated.

Let $D$ the open disk centered at $0$ with radius  $r = 1$.

> We define $h(z)=\frac{1+iz}{1-iz}$

How can we prove that

> $h(D) = \left\{z \in \mathbb{C} : \Re(z) > 0 \right\}$?

Maybe computing $h(\exp(i\theta))$ ?

Comment: Are you familiar with Möbius transformations and their properties?

Comment: No not really we used it in geometry how can it help here?

Comment: Möbius transformations map circles to circles or lines. In your case it is “easy” to see that the unit circle is mapped to the imaginary axis, and therefore its interior to the right half plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\Re (\frac {1+iz} {1-iz})= \Re (\frac {(1+iz) (1+i\overline {z})} {|1-iz|^{2}})$ and $(1+iz) (1+i\overline {z})=1-|z|^{2} +i(z+\overline {z})$; the real part of this is $1-|z|^{2}$ which is $>0$. So LHS $\subseteq$ RHS. For the reverse inclusion use the inverse map $g(w)=\frac {w-1} {i(1+w)}$. I will leave the calculation in this case to you. [What you have to show is $|w-1|< |w+1|$ if $\Re w >0$. Square both sides and expand the square].

Comment: Thanks , is this prove that there is a function $k$ such that $\exp(k(z)) = h(z)$

Comment: @Simba27 Yes, there is an analytic branch of logarithm on the right half plane and we can take $k(z)= \log h(z)$.